# Functional equation hint. How to start?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, functional-equations

If
$$f(x)-2f(1-x)=x$$ 
Solve
$$f(\sin x + \cos x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}-4}{6}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(1-x)-2f(x)=1-x$ and solve the system.

I got $x=15^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k$ or $x=75^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I did it. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @kenobe Welcome!

Comment: Pheew. Then I did something wrong. The key is to find f(x) which I have. But when I express f(sinx+cosx) things go wrong

Comment: @kenobe I got $f(x)=\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: So whenever I get this type of functional equation I am allowed to make the system by replacing the coefficients

Comment: @kenobe Yes, but for this type only. For example, the similar equation: $f(x)+2f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x$

Comment: Oh great. So in this one f(1/x)=(2x^2-1)/3x